# how can I use printf() and mod operation to get a decimal when my instance variables can only be Ints

Tags: java, modulus, integer-division

So I'm missing something here. I have a method that is supposed to compute and return the value of a stock portfolio. but it uses a mixed number which has a dollars portion and an eighths portion

```
public class StockPortfolio
{
  //Instance Vars 
  private String company;
  private int numOfShares;
  private int dollarSharePrice;
  private int eighthsSharePrice;

  public int portfolioValue()
  {
   int portVal = (dollarSharePrice * numOfShares) 
                 + (eighthsSharePrice * numOfShares) / 8;

   System.out.printf("Opening portfolio value: $%.2f" , portVal);

   return portVal;
  }
```

For the test class the values are `100` for `numOfShares`, `37` for `dollarSharePrice`
and `5` for `eighthsSharePrice`.

The expected output should look like this:

Opening portfolio value: $3762.50

my real trouble is just get the .50 to print. I've tried using % in different ways but to no avail. any help pointing me in the right direction is appreciated. I am at my wits end here.

Comment: But you declare `portVal` as `int`...

Comment: what should it be declared as? @alfasin

Comment: Fix the computation so that `portVal` is 376250.  I'll bet you can figure out how to get the right output after that.  Just make sure you do the division last.  When you're working with integers, `(a * b) / c` is not the same as `a * (b / c)`.

Comment: @PeterLion - Have a look at my answer.

Comment: @ajb I got `portVal` to get 376250. but I am getting a `IllegalFormatConversionException`

Comment: @PeterLion Are you using %f (or %.2f or something like that) in the format string?  After you get 376250, you will need to pass two integers to `System.out.printf`, and your format string will have two %d specifiers in it.  (P.S. I know there are other ways to do this such as R.J's answer, but I think it's instructive to see how to do this without any floating-point computation at all.  Floating-point computations usually involve rounding, and for non-scientific applications you often want exact answers.)

Answer (score 0):

```
float portVal = (float)9/4;
System.out.printf("Opening portfolio value: $%.2f" , portVal);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Opening portfolio value: $2.25
```

Comment: The topic says "the instance variables can only be ints"; does that apply to local variables in methods too?

Comment: @ajb if you deal with ints only you can't expect to print a fraction unless you do all the calculation inline (inside `printf`) and cast to float...

Comment: from instructions given it says all instance variables must be ints. so I'm assuming local variables can be of different type.

Comment: @alfasin Yes, you can get it to display the right answer without using any `float`s.  I'm just not clear on whether this is an assignment that doesn't allow floats as local variables.

Comment: @ajb using `double` ? :)

Comment: @alfasin See my comment up above.

Comment: @ajb even though it's correct - I can't see how it can help him in printing 0.5 or any other fraction without using a data type that support fractions (of course you can start calculating reminders and stuff - but this is way out of proportion to the talk IMHO).

Comment: @ajb I'm going to assume for now everything has to be an int. including locals. So how would I go about this? and thanks in advance.

Comment: @PeterLion See my comment up above.  You will call `printf` with two integers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `portVal` to print. Print it directly by doing something like this

```
System.out.printf("Opening portfolio value: $%.2f", (float)((dollarSharePrice * numOfShares) + (eighthsSharePrice * numOfShares) / 8));
```